# What is the MOST cost-effective solution to implement an image batch processing cluster on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning

I've some questions related to AWS Cloud practitioner, DevOps, and machine learning as I'm preparing for the AWS certifications.

What is the MOST cost-effective solution to implement an image batch processing cluster on AWS? Configuring the cluster software from a generic EC2 Linux image takes 30 minutes. The application cannot run in Docker containers and must run on Amazon EC2. The batch job stores checkpoint data on an NFS and can tolerate interruptions.

Should I Use GlusterFS on EC2 instances for checkpoint data? To run the batch job, configure EC2 instances manually. When the job completes, shut down the instances manually?

And also if there is a resource with solutions to the problems related to AWS Cloud practitioner, DevOps, and machine learning would be great.